# I am trying to get the value of a string from an if statement to the main class

Tags: android, string, variables

I have a bit of code where the user inputs numbers into EditText.

Depending on the value of what they enter I want to set a string that gets pulled by a dialog fragment (which I have replaced with a toast for now until I can get the string bit fixed.)

I get the pushups input which is changed to an int. 
That int is compared in the logic below it against certain standards. 
Depending on where it falls I want it to change a string that will be displayed later once all the logic is done.

```
package com.mynavy;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PRTC extends Activity {
    String pushs;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.prtc);
        Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);



    submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.agetxt);
            EditText pushups = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pushups);
            EditText situps = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.situps);
            EditText runtime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.runtime);
            String agetxt = String.valueOf(age.getText().toString());
            int agen = Integer.valueOf(agetxt);
            String pushtxt = String.valueOf(pushups.getText().toString());
            int pushn = Integer.valueOf(pushtxt);
            String sittxt = String.valueOf(situps.getText().toString());
            int sitn = Integer.valueOf(sittxt);
            String runtxt = String.valueOf(runtime.getText().toString());
            int runn = Integer.valueOf(runtxt);

//CHANGE THESE WHEN NEW INSTRUCTIONS COME OUT!!         
            if (agen >= 17 || agen <=20) {

                if (pushn >=20 || pushn <=30){
                    String pushs = "Good";
                }else if (pushn >=31 || pushn <=40){
                    String pushs = "Excellent";
                }else if (pushn >=41 || pushn <=50){
                    String pushs = "Outstanding";}}

                if (sitn >= 20 || sitn <= 30){
                    String sits = "Good";
                }else if (sitn >= 31 || sitn <=40){
                    String sits = "Excellent";
                }else if (sitn >= 41 || sitn <=50){
                    String sits = "Outstanding";

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), pushs + "Score.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "TEST FAILED!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        };});
}}
```

I know I have been asking a lot lately, but any help that is provided will be immensely appreciated as always!!

Comment: Please add a tag indicating the language.

Comment: I have updated my answer check it ..It is working in device with toast msg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redeclaring `pushs` which you already declared before onCreate which is global and pushs inside if/else block are local whose scope is within `{}` .Therefore you need to remove **String** used  before pushs from if and else block.Also your Toast is inside last else if block therefore you are not getting Toast msg.
Change your code like this

```
           if (agen >= 17 || agen <=20) {

                if (pushn >=20 || pushn <=30){
                    pushs = "Good";
                }else if (pushn >=31 || pushn <=40){
                    pushs = "Excellent";
                }else if (pushn >=41 || pushn <=50){
                   pushs = "Outstanding";
                 }


                if (sitn >= 20 || sitn <= 30){
                   String sits = "Good";
                }else if (sitn >= 31 || sitn <=40){
                   String sits = "Excellent";
                }else if (sitn >= 41 || sitn <=50){
                   String sits = "Outstanding";
                }

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), pushs + "Score.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "TEST FAILED!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

After this everything will work fine

Answer (score 2):

Your variables are known only in the scope where they've been declared. For example:

```
if(pushn >=20 || pushn <=30){
     String pushs = "Good";
}
```

`pushs` will not be recognized outside the scope if this `if`, you'll get a compilation error:

`pushs cannot be resolved to a variable`

Comment: So how can I get pushs to be seen outside of these statements is my question?

Comment: Put `String pushs;` outside the `if` scope.